# Drawing shapes on the image using swing

Tags: java

Here is my code. I am drawing rectangle, oval, lines on the image. Drawing a line is working fine. I can draw the rectangle, but it is not visible on mouse drag. How to modify this program to show rectangle on mouse drag. How to provide eraser for this program to erase only the shapes while preserving the background image.

```
package com.sobis.hindalco.bean

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;

public class ImageEdit extends JFrame{

    private BufferedImage originalImage;
    private BufferedImage canvasImage;
    private JPanel gui;
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;
    private JLabel output = new JLabel("You DooDoodle!");
    BufferedImage image=null;
    private BufferedImage colorSample = new BufferedImage(
            16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private int activeTool;
    public static final int RECTANGLE_TOOL = 0;
    public static final int DRAW_TOOL = 1;
    public static final int TEXT_TOOL = 2;
    public static final int ERASER_TOOL = 3;
    public static final int OVAL_TOOL = 4;
    Point startDrag, endDrag;
    private Point selectionStart;
    private Rectangle selection;
    private boolean dirty = false;
    // private Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(
    //   3,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,1.7f);
    private RenderingHints renderingHints;


    public JComponent getGui() {
        if(gui==null) {
            Map<Key, Object> hintsMap = new
                    HashMap();
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            renderingHints = new RenderingHints(hintsMap);
            setImage(new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,3,5,3));
            JPanel imageView = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            imageView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480,320));
            imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageView);
            imageView.add(imageLabel);
            imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new
                    ImageMouseMotionListener());
            imageLabel.addMouseListener(new ImageMouseListener());
            gui.add(imageScroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
            tb.setFloatable(false);
            JButton colorButton = new JButton("Color");
            colorButton.setMnemonic('o');            colorButton.setToolTipText("Choose a Color");

            ActionListener colorListener = new ActionListener() {




                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(
                            gui, "Choose a color", color);
                    if(c!=null) {
                        setColor(c);
                    }
                }



            };


            colorButton.addActionListener(colorListener);
            colorButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(colorSample));
            tb.add(colorButton);
            setColor(color);
            // final SpinnerNumberModel strokeModel =
            //     new SpinnerNumberModel(3,1,16,1);
            ///   JSpinner strokeSize = new JSpinner(strokeModel);

            ChangeListener strokeListener = new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                }
            };

            tb.addSeparator();
            ActionListener clearListener = new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    int result = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;
                    if(dirty) {
                        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                gui, "Erase the current painting?");
                    }

                    if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        clear(canvasImage);
                    }
                }

            };
            JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
            tb.add(clearButton);
            clearButton.addActionListener(clearListener);
            gui.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            JToolBar tools = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
            tools.setFloatable(false);
            JButton crop = new JButton("Crop");
            final JRadioButton select = new JRadioButton("Rectangle", true);
            final JRadioButton eraser = new JRadioButton("Eraser", true);
            final JRadioButton draw = new JRadioButton("Draw");
            final JRadioButton text = new JRadioButton("Text");




            final JRadioButton oval = new JRadioButton("oval");
            tools.add(select);
            tools.add(draw);
            tools.add(text);
            tools.add(eraser);
            tools.add(oval);
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(select);
            bg.add(text);
            bg.add(draw);
            bg.add(eraser);
            bg.add(oval);

            ActionListener toolGroupListener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    if(ae.getSource()==select) {
                        activeTool = RECTANGLE_TOOL;
                    }else if(ae.getSource()==draw) {
                        activeTool = DRAW_TOOL;
                    }else if(ae.getSource()==text) {
                        activeTool = TEXT_TOOL;
                    }else if(ae.getSource()==eraser) {
                        activeTool = ERASER_TOOL;
                    }else if(ae.getSource()==oval) {
                        activeTool = OVAL_TOOL;
                    }
                }

            };
            select.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            draw.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            text.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            eraser.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            oval.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            gui.add(output,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            clear(colorSample);
            clear(canvasImage);
        }

        return gui;
    }

    /** Clears the entire image area by painting it with the current color. */
    public void clear(BufferedImage bi) {

        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\images.jpeg"));
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        this.originalImage = image;
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        canvasImage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, gui);
        g.dispose();
        selection = new Rectangle(0,0,w,h);

        if(this.imageLabel!=null) {
            imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }



        if(gui!=null) {
            gui.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image1) {

        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\images.jpeg"));
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        this.originalImage = image;
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        canvasImage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, gui);
        g.dispose();
        selection = new Rectangle(0,0,w,h);
        if(this.imageLabel!=null) {
            imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
        if(gui!=null) {
            gui.invalidate();
        }
    }

    /** Set the current painting color and refresh any elements needed. */
    public void setColor(Color color) {

        this.color = color;
        clear(colorSample);
    }

    private JMenu getFileMenu(boolean webstart){

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic('f');
        //JMenuItem newImageItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        //newImageItem.setMnemonic('n');
        ActionListener newImage = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        360, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                clear(bi);
                setImage(bi);
            }
        };


        if(webstart) {
            //TODO Add open/save functionality using JNLP API
        }else{
            //TODO Add save functionality using J2SE API
            file.addSeparator();
            ActionListener saveListener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                    int result = ch.showSaveDialog(gui);
                    if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                        try {
                            File f = ch.getSelectedFile();
                            ImageIO.write(ImageEdit.this.canvasImage, "png",
                                    f); ImageEdit.this.originalImage =
                                    ImageEdit.this.canvasImage;
                            dirty = false;
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            showError(ioe);
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
            saveItem.addActionListener(saveListener);
            saveItem.setMnemonic('s');
            file.add(saveItem);
        }

        if(canExit()) {
            ActionListener exit = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            exitItem.setMnemonic('x');
            file.addSeparator();
            exitItem.addActionListener(exit);
            file.add(exitItem);
        }
        return file;
    }

    private void showError(Throwable t) {



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                gui,
                t.getMessage(),
                t.toString(),
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    JFileChooser chooser = null;


    public JFileChooser getFileChooser() {

        if(chooser==null) {
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileFilter ff= new FileNameExtensionFilter( "myfiles","jpg",

                    "jpeg","png");

            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(ff);
        }
        return chooser;
    }

    public boolean canExit() {

        boolean canExit = false;
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();

        if(sm==null) {
            canExit = true;
        }else{
            try {
                sm.checkExit(0);
                canExit = true;
            } catch(Exception stayFalse) {
            }
        }
        return canExit;
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar(boolean webstart){

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(this.getFileMenu(webstart));
        return mb;
    }

    public  void openPanel() {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // use default
                }

                ImageEdit bp = new ImageEdit();
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Editing");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setContentPane(bp.getGui());
                f.setJMenuBar(bp.getMenuBar(false));
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public void text(Point point) {

        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "Text to add",
                "Text");

        if(text!=null) {
            Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
            g.setColor(this.color);
            // g.setStroke(stroke);
            int n = 0;
            g.drawString(text,point.x,point.y);
            g.dispose();
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Point point) {

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        int n = 0;
        g.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point.x+n, point.y+n);
        g.dispose();
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    public void drawRectangle() {

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.drawRect(Math.min(startDrag.x, endDrag.x), Math.min(
                startDrag.y,endDrag.y), Math.abs(startDrag.x -endDrag.x),
                Math.abs(startDrag.y - endDrag.y));
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    public void eraser(Point point) {

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        int n = 0;
        g.clearRect(point.x, point.y, point.x+n, point.y+n);
        g.dispose();
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    public void oval() {

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        //   g.setStroke(stroke);
        int n = 0;
        // g.clearRect(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        g.dispose();
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    class ImageMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

            if(activeTool==ImageEdit.TEXT_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                text(arg0.getPoint());
            }else  if(activeTool==ImageEdit.ERASER_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                eraser(arg0.getPoint());
            }else  if(activeTool==ImageEdit.ERASER_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            }else{
                startDrag = new Point(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
                endDrag = startDrag;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

            if(activeTool==ImageEdit.RECTANGLE_TOOL) {
                endDrag = new Point( arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
                drawRectangle();
            }
        }
    }

    class ImageMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {

            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
            endDrag = new Point( arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
            if(activeTool==ImageEdit.DRAW_TOOL) {
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            }else if(activeTool==ImageEdit.RECTANGLE_TOOL) {
                endDrag = new Point( arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
            }else if(activeTool==ImageEdit.OVAL_TOOL) {
                oval();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
        }
    }

    private void reportPositionAndColor(MouseEvent me) {

        String text = "";
        if(activeTool==ImageEdit.RECTANGLE_TOOL) {
            text += "Selection (X,Y:WxH): " +
                    (int)selection.getX() +
                    "," +
                    (int)selection.getY() +
                    ":" +
                    (int)selection.getWidth() +
                    "x" +
                    (int)selection.getHeight();
        }else{
            text += "X,Y: " + (me.getPoint().x+1) + "," +
                    (me.getPoint().y+1);
        }
        output.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

> How to modify this program to show rectangle on mouse drag.

You can check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Both approaches draw a temporary Rectangle as you hold down the mouse and drag it. Basically you need to handle mousePressed to track the starting point, mouseDragged to get the current mouse point (and to a repaint()) and mouseReleased to save the actual Rectangle.

> How to provide eraser for this program to erase only the shapes while preserving the background image.

You would probably want to use the `Draw On Component` approach from the above link. Then you would iterated through the List of shapes to determine if the mouse point is contained by the shape. If so, then you would remove the shapes from the List. So this will only permit erasure of entire shapes.